# Equivalent of MSSQL with statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

is there any equivalent to the following statement in mysql ?

```
With Tmp1 as (
        Select Distinct EmpID, TypeID 
        From tb_deductionBalance
), Tmp2 as (
    Select *,
       row_number() OVER ( order by empID /* no employeeID in Tmp1 */) as RowNum 
    From Tmp1
)
Select * From Tmp2
Where RowNum Between @Start and @End
```

I have to migrate an mssql database to mysql and there are plenty of such statements which would take much more time to recreate in mysql if it cannot be translated.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL does not support `common table expressions`.  Instead you'll have to use subqueries.  Also doesn't support analytic functions such as `row_number` -- you'll have to write your own.

Comment: @sgeddes, that is exactly what the OP is asking, **Equivalent of MSSQL with statement in MYSQL**

Comment: @astander -- I edited my comment.  OP can use subqueries instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, TypeID
FROM tb_deductionBalance
ORDER BY empID
LIMIT YourStartNumber - 1, YourEndNumber - YourStartNumber
```

Unfortunately, you can't use variables in `LIMIT`, so you'll need to use actual integers there. For instance, if you want results from the rows 3 to 10, you'll need to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, TypeID
FROM tb_deductionBalance
ORDER BY empID
LIMIT 2, 7
```